# pager is not working when print views

Tags: 7, views

I've created one [view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with used of php code for some fields in it, and set pager on it too. It's working fine whenever i created given link of view but actually I print that same view on another basic page, using this php code:

`<?php print views_embed_view($viewName); ?>`

on that basic page pager is not working, because on that page the pager link is generated with that basic page url link not with views url link. can anyone give solution when i print the same view on basic page and also pager can work over there perfect?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used Views PHP, this is a known issue

[Views Pager is hidden (7.x-2.x)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2484407)

[Pager disappears when Global: PHP used in Views 3.8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165)

You have to apply one of the patches to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from one known issue, and worked properly for me. Here is the [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2123315) of it and patches.